# Accidently created a new drawable values resource and getting Build errors. How to delete the resources?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I accidentally created new drawable value resources  :
[Here is a snapshot of how i did it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGvHM.png)

How can i delete these two resource ?
[the two resorces i want to delete : Jobs,jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KinkJ.png)

I am getting this build error:

> /home/thebitshoes/Desktop/ClassProject/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml
>   Error:(484, 69) String types not allowed (at 'Jobs' with value '').
>   Error:(484, 69) String types not allowed (at 'Jobs' with value '').
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: Path you shared have "debug" so you go to non debug file and then delete it.

Comment: Select the resources, hit the DELETE button, confirm.

Comment: @ChetanJoshi : I am unable to locate it. I am not even seeing the file named Job or jobs by going into the drawable folder. Where is it saved in the system?

Comment: @Rotwang unable to locate the files via file manager in UBUNTU. I cant find job or Jobs in my app/src/main/res/drawable folder nor any where else

Comment: Then simply clean your project to rebuild its cache. It seems your have some cached "ghost" files.

Comment: have you deleted intermediates in build folder. Try it

Comment: @ChetanJoshi Do i have to delete everything in the intermediates folder or the whole intermediates folder ?

Comment: you may delete whole intermediates , its generated folder so when you clean your project its recreated its self  .

Comment: @ChetanJoshi :  This is how i made the mistake . Consider this scenario : On the Spinner Widget property > Entries >(with Drawable being selected by default) Add new Resource > New Drawable Value >Resource Name : Job

Comment: are you able to change resource name , if yes then change Job to job  like below answer .

Comment: Capital letters aren't valid characters. You can only use `a...z`, `0...9`, `.` and `_`.

Comment: If only i can locat the Job / jobs folder or file , I could change it. I am unable to change

Comment: @Rotwang I agree , we dont have to use capital letters. But now, how can i even change ?

Comment: After deleting the files, clean and rebuild the project. The R file will be re-generated.

Comment: is this the complete error log?

Answer (score 0):

Close the project, go to the specific file externally and remove the resource value(if this doesn't work then delete file) and then start the project again. It helped me.

Comment: No need to close the project

Answer (score 0):

Okay!! here I figured it out :

My values folder contained an XML file named refs.xml . Inside the file , i had two resource items Jobs , job . I deleted the refs file itself . Now its working!!!

Thank you all!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete your xml file or rename it with small character and valid file name, 
in App module delete "build" directory, then rebuild the directory hope this helps. Because build directory has old references.